# Space in IE - FF displaying fine

Tags: css, internet-explorer, space

At my personal website while viewing a single post, i have an overview DIV, and in FF it has no space between the main header and the excerpt, but in IE there is a space there. Any idea on how I can get rid of that?

I have FireBug for FF and i installed IE Developer Toolbar on my other PC to try to inspect the code to find the problem, with no luck.

http://www.ryancoughlin.com/2008/12/19/dunks-or-starbucks-who-comes-out-on-top/

That is an example.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like the div containing the calendar date is pushing it down because it's the excerpt has a width set to 100%, set it to 90% and you see it will go to the top.

edit: if you change the width ofthe container of the calendar DEC 19th thing to 80 from 88 it should look better

here's what i see in the IE Developer Toolbar

http://imagebin.antiyes.com/451

Comment: In other words: change line 266 of style000.css to width:80px;  This changes the alignment, though; the background image needs to be modified.

Comment: An alternative solution is to use position: absolute; on the post date.  However, this and your second method (calendar width) will shift the content's text to the left a bit.  That can be fixed, though.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a [reset css file](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2008/01/15/resetting-again/) before you use any other style sheets. This will reset the inconsistencies in standard css between browsers.

Comment: Hey Marius I am using Blueprint CSS and there is a reset style included within.

Thanks

Ryan